# How to send data to ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, blockchain.info-api

In normal applications and centralized database:
The application hold list of elements and application push the elements into database so database store the elements.

In decentalized applications and blockchain:
smart contract contain arrary of stuct

What need to be done to push the elemets in to blockchain?

Comment: Making a decentralized app often means rethinking the whole structure of your application. It's rarely as simple as "change a few lines to sprinkle some blockchain in." (dare I say: never?) Storage and computation is many orders of magnitude more expensive, so you'll want to think about what stays on your servers and what goes in the blockchain. In general, storing data is as simple as creating a smart contract with a variable, and setting the variable value by issuing a transaction.